# Rhino JS interpreter vs SpiderMonkey interpreter - different return value

Tags: javascript

I am using two different Javascript interpreters - Rhino and SpiderMonkey through terminal.So when I want to call for example toString() and valueOf() methods on some object I get different results, depends on interpreter. Like this:

```
**Rhino** 
  var f={x:10}  f.toString() result [object Object] 

                f.valueOf() result [object Object] 


**SpiderMonkey**
  var f={x:10}  f.toString() result  "[object Object]" //in quotes 

                f.valueOf() result ({x:10})
```

I know that Rhino is written in Java, and SpiderMonkey in C.Why do I got different results ?

Answer (score 2):

The return values are the same, but they're being displayed differently. Rhino is just printing out `result.toString()` where `result` is the value of the expression you just evaluated. In both cases you get the same thing because `f.valueOf() === f` so `f.valueOf().toString() === f.toString().toString()`.

SpiderMonkey appears to be printing `result.toSource()` instead, which puts quotes around the string and formats `f.valueOf()` as an object literal.